# kotlin runCatching force default return

Tags: kotlin, try-catch

The constructor of `runCatching` in kotlin annoys me.
If it is supposed to replace `try{}catch{}` why I need to still have a default return when using it?

IS THERE ANY WAY TO AVOID DEFAULT RETURN?

example

```
fun foo(): String {

    objects
        .runCathing { anyFunctionThatReturnsString() }
        .onFailure {
            return "error"
        }
        .onSucess {
            return "sucess"
        }

    return ""
}
```

on standard java try{}catch{} if i have return inside try and inside catch i don't need a default return out of the block....

why on kotlin i need it? any way to avoid this?

Comment: `runCatching` is not meant for business code, and catches way more things than you should want to catch. Just use try/catch with the actual exceptions you want to catch. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847513/when-and-how-to-use-result-in-kotlin

Comment: You can use [`Result<T>.fold()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/fold.html) to handle both success or failure branches, without the need for an unnecessary return.

Answer (score 0):

Because `runCatching` doesn't return the type directly but returns Kotlin `Result`

```
    fun foo(): String {
        val foo: Result<String> = runCatching {
            ""
        }.onFailure { 
            ""
        }.onSuccess { "" }
        
        return foo.getOrElse { "" }
    }
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run-catching.html

Since every lambda is returning `Result` you can collapse to the `return` like this:

```
fun foo(): String {
        return runCatching {
            ""
        }.onFailure {
            ""
        }.onSuccess { 
            "" 
        }.getOrNull() ?: ""
    }
```

Comment: `runCatching` isn't really standard Kotlin.  Why would you not use a normal try/catch?

Answer (score 0):

> If it is supposed to replace `try{}catch{}`...

It's **not** supposed to replace try/catch.

It's clumsy to use like that because that's not what `runCatching` is for. You should use try/catch:

```
fun foo(): String {
    return try {
        objects.anyFunctionThatReturnsString()
        "success"
    } catch (e: Exception) { // In practice this should be specific to the expected errors that the above function can throw.
        "error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `runCatching`, you are probably doing something wrong with your code, unless you are already out of your domain layer and for example generating error message for UI.

If you really want to do something like this, I suggest you just create your own method/extension. For example (I find a bit weird to have 2 blocks for "success" - running code and then handling success):

```
fun foo(): String {
    return chooseBetterName(
        { "" },
        onSuccess = { "success" },
        onFailure = { "error" }
    )
}

fun <T> chooseBetterName(block: () -> T, onSuccess: (T) -> T, onFailure: (Exception) -> T): T {
    return try {
        onSuccess(block())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        onFailure(e)
    }
}
```