# Unable to return Result on success

Tags: kotlin

I have a function as below:

```
 inline fun <reified T> deserialize(payload: SdkBytes): Result<T> {
        return runCatching {
            Json.decodeFromString(payload.asUtf8String())
        }
    }
```

I am invoking an AWS Lambda function which checks wether a functionError has occured or not and based on that deserializes the payload:

```
private fun InvokeResponse.Response(): Result<Response> {
        return runCatching {
            val error = this.functionError()
            if (error.isNullOrBlank()) {
                deserialize<Response>(this.payload())
            }
            throw RuntimeException(error)
        }
    }
```

and I am using it to return responseCodes as below

```
response.statusCode = lambdaResponse
            .Response()
            .fold(::onSucess, ::onFailure)
        return response
```

However for all the cases it goes to onFailure. What I want is that it should go to OnSucess if it is able to deserialize but seems like I am not getting a `Result` after `deserialize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like to point out that `runCatching` and `Result` should probably not be used in any of those cases: [When and how to use Result in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847513/when-and-how-to-use-result-in-kotlin/70847760#70847760)

Now, looking at `Response()`*, you are always throwing a `RuntimeException` because your `throw` is after the `if`, but not in an `else` clause:

```kotlin
if (error.isNullOrBlank()) {
    deserialize<Response>(this.payload())
}
throw RuntimeException(error) // this runs even when there is no error
```

You probably wanted:

```kotlin
if (error.isNullOrBlank()) {
    deserialize<Response>(this.payload())
} else {
    throw RuntimeException(error)
}
```

That said, you could instead remove `runCatching` altogether and either use your own result type (no need for throw) or just catch exceptions at a higher level.

*By the way, consider a lowercase `R` in `Response()` to follow Kotlin conventions for functions.