# Kotlin Result Function Chaining Patterns

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Question for you smart people.   I'm glad to see some functional objects in Kotlin such as Result, but I'm struggling how to use it effectively.  Here's a couple of patterns that I came up with, but their must be better.

I'll just call this the imperative pattern for calling a series of functions that return a `Result<*>` instance:

```
fun myFunc(): Result<String> { 
   return runCatching { 
       val x = f1().getOrThrow() 
       val y = f2(x).getOrThrow()
       val z = f3(y).getOrThrow() 
       forTheWin(x, y, z).getOrThrow()
   } 
}
```

This works and it's certainly easy for imperative programmers to pick up and use.

However, it doesn't feel right to me.   I would prefer some sort of chaining operation such as `f(g())`, but what do you do with a `Result<Result<T>>`, so I came up with some simple flattening functions:

```
fun <T> Result<Result<T>>.flatten(): Result<T> = when {
    isSuccess -> getOrNull()!!
    else -> Result.failure(this.exceptionOrNull()!!)
}

fun <T, R> Result<Result<T>>.flatmap(f: (T) -> R): Result<R> = this.flatten().map(f)

fun <T> Result<T>.mapFailure(f: (Throwable) -> Throwable): Result<T> = 
    this.recoverCatching { throw f.invoke(it) }
```

such that `f(g()).flatten()` returns a `Result<T>`.   (I've tried and failed to write a `flatten()` that will flatten a Result of arbitrary depth.)

Taking the above example, I can rewrite it as:

```
fun myFunc(): Result<String> { 
   return f1().map { x -> 
          f2(x).flatMap { y -> 
             f3(y).flatMap { z -> 
                forTheWin(x, y, z)
       }.flatten
}
```

which still isn't satisfying as I usually have to do some careful massaging to get the map, flatmaps, and flatten to balance into a simple `Result<T>` result.   If I could just call a single `flatten()`, it would go a long way to being a usable pattern.

Question:  Does anybody have a pattern to chain functions that return Result types?  Or, are there better functional objects in Kotlin?

Comment: `Result` is not meant to be used in application code. If you want a real functional approach, you should instead use libraries like Arrow, which provide the facilities you need. Vanilla Kotlin is not designed with this programming style in mind, so you'll keep hitting road blocks such as these verbose unsatisfying constructs. As a side reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847513

Comment: @Joffrey I can't argue with that, unfortunately, the organization has been resistant to Arrow.

Comment: @Joffrey btw, what do mean that "Result is not meant to be used in application code"?   I use it all the time and it perfect for mapping a result to a HttpResponse for rest services.   Otherwise, you'd end up dorking around with Exception handling.

Comment: Not answering the question, but `getOrNull()!!` in this case is risky since it'll throw an NPE in the perfectly valid case where `T` is nullable and the value is `null`. What you want instead is `getOrNull() as T`.

Comment: @Kurt what I mean is that it should only really be used in general "framework" code dealing with executions of blocks of code, when they need to handle errors in a special way (such as the coroutines framework). Application (or "business") code should instead create its own sealed type to define business errors. I elaborated quite a bit in the answer I linked.

Comment: And you need to use it very carefully if you use it in coroutines because it catches *everything* which will mess up coroutine cancellation machinery.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic.  You're probably right if the expected result is nullable.   Part of the reason that prefer not to use Kotlin is the nullables, but I'll have to figure out different.  (And, I'd really love it if the org would adopt a framework).